# Image for <option> not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

My requirement is to add images inside `<option>`. I have used the below code to display images in FF.

[Script]

```
       var items = $("#ShipCountry option").children();    //dropdown options     

        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            $(items[i]).html("<img src='/Images/" + $(items[i]).html() + ".gif'></img>"); // adding image

        }
```

This code works in FF but not in other browsers. I do not want to implement this logic using CSS as i need to display large number of images (options).

Is that possible without CSS for all browsers?

Comment: Can you possibly fiddle this?

Comment: It is better to implement your own DDL using `<div>` blocks and do whatever you want with it. Changing `<option>` elements won't be crossbrowser in any case.

Comment: I'm not sure about other browsers, but in IE only permitted content for `option` is text. Also usable CSS styles are very limited.

Comment: Which browsers? I know in most older IE versions, and maybe the latest one, the drop down box is an OS widget, thus not subject to many CSS constraints.  And I don't think HTML specs allow `img` tags in `option` tags in any case...I'm surprised Firefox allows it.

Comment: You're selecting the children of all your options? Wouldn't you rather just select the options themselves with `$("#ShipCountry").children();` or `$("#ShipCountry").find('option')`?

Comment: But anyway, HTML tags inside options are not allowed [according to the standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html)

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable comments. Most likely i would rather go for an alternative way to achieve this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make this work cross-browser, as lots of browsers restrict what you can do with the `<option>` tag. I'm surprised it works in Firefox to be honest. You might want to look into [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) which makes this possible cross browser, and has great documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will go for the alternative way.